# looking for a Lua-based solution for splitting a string into two or more components

Tags: string, lua

This is my first posting to this site, so please bear with me.

Consider the following, somewhat representative string:

```
fld u.a. ldfjal \verb*u.a.* dlf \lstinline$u.a.$ u.a. dfla \url{u.a.}rrr
```

For some background: `\verb*....*` and `\lstline$...$` are LaTeX macros whose arguments aren't delimited by matching curly braces but, instead, by a common character: `*` in the case of `\verb`, and `$` in the case of `\lstinline`. An important point is that the delimiter characters can be any printable ASCII character *except* `{` and `}`; one should not assume that `*` or `$` will be used as delimiters in all (or even any) cases. Separately, `\url{...}` is a LaTeX macro whose argument is delimited by curly braces. The full string should be assume to contain utf8-encoded characters; for simplicity, let's assume they're pure ASCII characters.

I'm looking to create a (hopefully reasonably efficient...) Lua-based way to split the full string into two sets of substrings: (a) the parts that consist of LaTeX macros and their associated arguments and (b) the other parts. The eventual goal is to feed the "other parts" to a string.gsub function call.

Turning to the preceding example, how might one separate the string

```
fld u.a. ldfjal \verb*u.a.* dlf \lstinline$u.a.$ u.a. dfla \url{u.a.}rrr
```

into "Y" (inside a verbatim-like macro) and "N" (not inside a verbatim-like macro) components, i.e.,

```
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNYYYYYYYYYYYNNNNNYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYNNNNNNNNNNNYYYYYYYYYYNNN
```

Oh, each full string is guaranteed to have "N" components, but there may be no "Y" components. The string may, in principle, start and end with either "N" or "Y" components.

I've been trying to come up with a solution that uses Lua's string library functions, but haven't gotten far at all. :-(

Comment: it would make things more clear if you'd give the expected output for your example input string instead of giving some NNNNYYYNNN thing

Comment: @Piglet - Thanks. Ideally, the "output" could be fed into a `string.gsub` function whose third component would be a Lua function, which doesn't operate on the "Y" parts and does some further string manipulation (via yet another string.gsub call) on the "N" parts. If it's too difficult to do this, I'd be perfectly happy with a sequential algorithm that separates out the "Y" and "N" parts (with me applying some further processing to the "N" parts). Again, the "N" parts would be the LaTeX macros `\verb`, `lstlinline`, `\url` and their respective arguments. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Based on the original problem at [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386224) it is not guaranteed that a full string does contain "N" components. Additionally the commands could be nested like `\verb|\lstinline+nested use+|` in which case only the outermost command in question needs to be evaluated until the corresponding closing symbol as a "Y" part, but still each string might contain any number of the commands in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that:

- macros names are consist of only letters and `@`
- a delimiter may only be a digit or punctuation character except `@\`

The code:

```
-- specify number of parameters for every macro,
-- use negative numbers for macros supporting matching pair of curly braces {} 
local all_macros = {
   verb = 1,
   url = -1,
   lstinline = -1,
   ["@Some@Macros"] = -2,
   makeatletter = 0
}

-- list all the delimiters (only punctuation and digits)
local all_delimiters = [[!"#$%&'*+,-./:;<=>?^_`|~()[]{}0123456789]]

-- specify a function for processing N-part of the string
local function convert(N_substring)
   return N_substring:upper()
end


-- Now do the processing
local s = [[
fld u.a. ldfjal \verb{u.a.{ dlf \lstinline{u.a.} u.a. dfla
\url{u.a.}rrr \@Some@Macros~u.a.~{u.a.}{u.a.}qq\verb|\lstinline+nested use+qqq|q
]]
s = s:gsub("\\([%a@]+)",
   function(macro_name)
      if all_macros[macro_name] then
         return
            "\1\\"..macro_name
            ..(all_macros[macro_name] < 0 and "\2" or "\3")
            :rep(math.abs(all_macros[macro_name]) + 1)
      end
   end
)
repeat
   local old_length = #s
   repeat
      local old_length = #s
      s = s:gsub("\2(\2+)(%b{})", "%2%1")
   until old_length == #s
   s = s:gsub("[\2\3]([\2\3]+)((["..all_delimiters:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."])(.-)%3)", "%2%1")
until old_length == #s
s = ("\2"..s.."\1"):gsub("[\2\3]+([^\2\3]-)\1", convert):gsub("[\1\2\3]", "")

-- Print the result
print(s)
```

Output:

```
FLD U.A. LDFJAL \verb{u.a.{ DLF \lstinline{u.a.} U.A. DFLA
\url{u.a.}RRR \@Some@Macros~u.a.~{u.a.}{U.A.}QQ\verb|\lstinline+nested use+qqq|Q
```

Comment: I really like your solution, but: the command `\verb` can't have its argument enclosed by a matching pair of curly braces but might be used like this: `\verb{test{` which is valid syntax for LaTeX but not detected by your solution. In the meantime `\lstinline` can be used with `\lstinline{test}` but not with `\lstinline{test{` or `\lstinline}test}`. Still your solution is amazing!

Comment: Does someone really write things like `\verb{test{` ?

Comment: I won't but it is possible and might be reasonable if you need the other characters inside the verbatim expression. Also `\verb` and `\lstinline` might be delimited by matching digits (which are not allowed in macro names without the use of special macros like `\csname`)

Comment: Wow, your code is exactly what I needed!! Thanks so much. Please see [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386235/5001) for an application of your code to a real-life typesetting problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s=[[
fld u.a. ldfjal \verb*u.a.* dlf \lstinline$u.a.$ u.a. dfla \url{u.a.}rrr
]]

for a,b,c in s:gmatch("(\\verb(.)(.-)%2)") do
    print(a,b,c)
end
```

You'll have to do one loop for each primitive you're interested in, but at least the delimiter part takes care of itself.

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself familiar with Lua's string patterns.

`"[^}{]"` will match any character but `"}"` or `"{"` for example.

Captures:

`"{([^{}]*)}"` this would capture any number of characters but `"{"` or `"}"` which are enclosed by curly braces...

All you have to do is puzzle everything together.

https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

Comment: That does not really help sorting out strings separated with any character like `\verb+something+` where the separator is `+`, or `\verb$something$` where the separator is `$`. The challenge behind this is [hidden here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386235/124577).

Comment: @TeXnician I don't know what you mean. can you please give another example? because "\verb[^{}]([^{}]*)[^{}]" perfectly gives "something" out of "\verb$something$" or "\verb+something+" or "\verbasomethinga", you name it.

Comment: Silly me, forget it, you're right. The only conflict I see with the OP's task is that the `\url{something}` thing can't be captured simultaneously.

Comment: @TeXnician - The `\url{something}` part is actually quite easy: it's matched by `\url%b{}`. :-)

Comment: @Piglet - I'm not really looking to extract `something` from  `\verb&something&`. Rather, I'm looking to extract `\verb&something&` from, say, `djfaldfja;l\verb&something&dlfja;slfdjal`. The tricky issue is that the delimiter character (here: `&`) is not known in advance. Instead, it must be determined from the context, as the very first character after `\verb`.

Comment: @Mico then do a first run to get the opening & and then a second run with the full pattern. unfortunately you cannot do this in a single match